# Water dish vs bottle for dog kennel?

Tags: dogs

Transporting a Cocker Spaniel on a 10 hour direct flight.

Is it better to use a traditional open-top water dish or a water bottle (like might be used for rabbits, but larger)?

My concern with the water dish is that the water will spill and he won't have enough during the flight.

My concern with the water bottle is that he won't be able to get enough water from the nipple, or won't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned that your dog won't know how to use the bottle, why not have a test run?
Water bottles are pretty cheap and if it doesn't work out you can probably return it.

I wouldn't recommend the open water dish.  It's likely to spill and your dog will have a miserable 10 hour flight, which is already stressful enough without being thirsty and wet.  A nice in between is a water pail.  It's deeper than a regular dish and you can clip it to the side of the crate for stability.

EDIT: I've had success with a flat sided pail, like this one: http://amzn.to/2lcP4hN
I typically use a very small carabiner or other clip to attach the pail to the side of the crate in addition to the built in hooks for maximum hold and stability.

Comment: I've had success with a flat sided pail, like this one: http://amzn.to/2lcP4hN I typically use a very small carabiner or other clip to attach the pail to the side of the crate in addition to the built in hooks for maximum hold and stability.

Comment: That's the one I ordered yesterday! My plan is either zipties or small carabiner. Did you also strap a funnel on the outside of the kennel to make refilling easy?

Comment: I've typically used a watering can, but an attached funnel would work as well.